# Can't Getting called onReceive() when package cleared in android

Tags: android

I am using this code for register a broadcast receiver for package

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.abc.abc.activity.Receiver"
  android:exported="true" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter></receiver>
```

But I am not getting it called when I clear my application's data

Can anyone help me 
Thanks In advance.!

Answer (score 3):

I tested it now and it's work for me with this code:

```
<receiver android:name=".permission_policy.AppInstallRemoveReceiver">
             <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                  <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
                  <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                  <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED"/>
                  <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                  <data android:scheme="package"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this answer but it didn't works for me

Comment: It gets calling when I clear data of another app which I installed in my mobile but I want to call it when I clear my own app's data

Comment: In that case, the only solution i can think of is to build a new app  App-B  that will be call when cleaning App-A  happens

Comment: The same issue I am facing here. But its not good idea to create a new app to just watch the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android SDK [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED) on android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED

> Note that the cleared package does not receive this broadcast

So it looks like you will not be informed that your own data has been cleared.